# How to create a network folder between a windows machine and a ubuntu machine?

Tags: 20.04, file-sharing

I need help to mount an network folder between Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa (Home network server for me but using normal Ubuntu desktop) and my windows 10 version 1903. I don't know how to configure samba. I also followed lots of YouTube tutorials but nothing worked for me.

Is there is any way by which I can easily share a network folder between Windows (want to share my documents folder with Ubuntu) without complications?